# Error running "func azure functionapp publish ..." inside docker container

Tags: azure, docker

I am working on a prototype where I need to run a deploy command at run time, in my docker image I install Azure CLI and core web tools, but at runtime the deploy command always fails inside the docker container, the issue comes from core web tools cli: "System. Exception: Cannot find the Local Application Data.".

Note: I have been trying to solve this for couple of days now, it is not related to the architecture where docker daemon is running since I have tested it on mac, windows, azure directly. Both amd64 and x86_64. The image is based on ubuntu:20.04

full error:

```
System.Exception: Cannot find the Local Application Data.
   at Azure.Functions.Cli.Utilities.EnsureCoreToolsLocalData() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Azure.Functions.Cli\Common\Utilities.cs:line 180
   at Azure.Functions.Cli.Telemetry.PersistenceChannel.StorageService.VerifyOrSetDefaultStorageDirectoryPath(String desireStorageDirectoryPath) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Azure.Functions.Cli\Telemetry\PersistenceChannel\StorageService.cs:line 96
   at Azure.Functions.Cli.Telemetry.PersistenceChannel.StorageService.Init(String storageDirectoryPath) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Azure.Functions.Cli\Telemetry\PersistenceChannel\StorageService.cs:line 76
   at Azure.Functions.Cli.Telemetry.PersistenceChannel.PersistenceChannel..ctor(String storageDirectoryPath, Int32 sendersCount) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Azure.Functions.Cli\Telemetry\PersistenceChannel\PersistenceChannel.cs:line 41
   at Azure.Functions.Cli.Telemetry.Telemetry.InitializeTelemetry() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Azure.Functions.Cli\Telemetry\Telemetry.cs:line 93
```

I want to be able to call the core web tools at run time inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a new Azure test function.
- Enable `Docker` while creating Azure function and it will create a default `Dockerfile` to run the Azure function as a Docker image.

[image]

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:4 AS base
WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["FunctionApp47.csproj", "FunctionApp47/"]
RUN dotnet restore "FunctionApp47.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/FunctionApp47"
RUN dotnet build "FunctionApp47.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "FunctionApp47.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true
```

[image]

- Include your commands to install Azure CLI and core Tools in `Dockerfile`.

(or)
As mentioned in [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/run-azure-cli-docker#start-the-docker-container-with-azure-cli-preinstalled), you can also preinstall `Azure-cli` by using the below command:
`docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli`

[image]

- Build and run the Docker image using the commands:
  `docker build -t <Image_Name> .`
  `docker run -p 8080:80 -it <Image_Name>`

---

(OR)
Follow and try to use the below given Dockerfile code to install Azure CLI and Core Tools in container:

```
# Installing dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y curl gnupg && \
    curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | bash && \
    apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-3.1 && \
    apt-get install -y azure-functions-core-tools-3 && 

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the application files
COPY . .

# Run the deploy command
CMD ["func", "azure", "functionapp", "publish", "<function_app_name>"]
```

[image]